# Best practice to send a ASP.Net Core Web App project to someone?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm a newbie in ASP.NET projects and I am wondering how do I share my finished C# project to someone by email so they can run it (IIS Express) on their machine ? It's for a job offer skill test.

Do I need to send every files and folders or i can just send the source code?

The project folder is 6MB so i can't send it by email.

Sorry for my English and thanks for help !

Comment: Also, now i have a XunitTest project. I am wondering you do I bundle my solution project and my XunitTest project ? They seems to be in two different repos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to send it could be by uploading it to GitHub and sharing the repository link. Since it is for a job it will also showcase that you are Version Control savvy.

You can also include a `README.md` file there that describes the app.

Comment: Thank you, should I include the bin folder ?

Comment: @Gregory it is customary not to - the person who will then pull your repository should be able to rebuilt your project. In the `README.md` file you can include any prerequisites or dependencies needed to build the project e.g. .NET version.

You know your audience better tho, so it is up to you to include `bin` or not

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this has anything to do with ASP.net. It's just a question on how to transfer a large file isn't it? If so, 6mb isn't really that large for email nowadays. Most mail servers will handle that fine. But if email is a problem, put it on one of the myriad of fileshare platforms available such as Dropbox.

As for what specific files you need to send. That would depend on the requirements the company gave you - but I'd imagine they certainly need to see your source code and likely want the entire thing to be runnable. So send whatever is needed so they can easily run it.

Have you tried zipping it up? Source code will generally zip very effectively to a much smaller file as it contains so much repetition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I will try zipping it? Should I include all dependencies, dll and bin ?

Answer (score 1):

Upload the zip file to your google drive and then send it as a drive attachment. (This is actually Google’s recommendation) Or just simply share it with them. I recommend that attachment be as small as possible in the event that the user your sending it to has a mail quota.

Comment: Ok thank you. Should i delete the bin folder before since it's big ?